# Project can't find dll in Visual Studio 2015 PrivateAssemblies

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

We are upgrading from vs2013 to vs2015.  In vs2013 we have a common dll used by the .rdlc reports in two projects that is placed in the PrivateAssemblies of vs2013.
When I place the dll in the PrivateAssemblies of vs2015 all the projects that use the reports stop building. Do I need to place the dll in a different location in vs2015?
**Error while loading code module: ‘Reports.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Reports.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but this is the where I placed that shared dll and the projects are now finding it and building.
**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin**